# Prove asymptotic bound?

Tags: computer-science, asymptotics

Prove: 
$$n^b = \mathcal{o}(a^n)$$

for and constants $b$ and $a$, where $a > 1$. The book states that:

$$\lim_{ n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n^b}{a^n} = 0$$

The book doesn't prove the limit though. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

That is one way to prove that exponential complexity ($a^n$) is always greater than polynomial complexity ($n^b$). Here is the formal definition of the statement $n^b$ is $o(a^n)$:

$$n^b \text{ is } o(a^n) \iff \{\forall c>0,n>n_0: |n^b| < c|a^n| \}$$
$$ \frac{n^b}{a^n} < c $$
$$ \frac{a^{b \log_a(n)}}{a^{n}}< c \quad (\text{Since }n=a^{\log_an})$$
$$ a^{b \log_a(n)-n} < c $$

This is expression is true since $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a^{b \log_a(n)-n} = 0$.

$$\therefore n^b \text{ is } o(a^n)$$

The limit from the book should be: $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n^b}{a^n} = 0$$

which shows that $a^n$ dominates the expression $n^b$ (definition of little o). Hope this helps!

Comment: Could you prove that $$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} a^ {b\log_a (n) - n} = 0$$

Comment: @user70518, see the solution below.

Answer (score 1):

You are right. The correct statement should be
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^b}{a^n}=0 $$
for any constants $a,b$ and $a>1$. For $b\le 0$, it is trivial. For $b>0$, let $m$ be an integer such that $0\le m\le k<m+1$. Let $c=a-1>0$. Since, for $n>m+1$,
$$ a^n=(1+c)^n=\sum_{k=0}\binom{n}{k}c^k\ge \binom{n}{m+1}c^{m+1} $$
we have
$$0<\frac{n^b}{a^n}<\frac{n^b}{\binom{n}{m+1}c^{m+1}}. $$
It is easy to check 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^b}{\binom{n}{m+1}}=0. $$
Thus
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^b}{a^n}=0. $$

Comment: $n^b=o(a^n)$ is a correct statement. It means precisely yhe limit thing.